# Hide and show not working in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have two list  in html in single page .. i want when my page is loaded only one list will  be display, and other  will be hidden,,

but when my page is loaded , both list are there ,, after some delay ,, the other get hidden

Here My Html code

```
<div id="menu" class="menu-v" data-role="content">

    <ul  class="listUl">
           <c:forEach items="${model.vaults}" var="vault" varStatus="count">
            <li class="outer" id="${vault.vaultId}" name="${vault.vaultName}">
              <div  class="listViewitem">
                <div class="squaredThree">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="${vault.vaultId}" name="check" />
                    <label for="${vault.vaultId}"></label>
                </div> 
                    <span>${vault.vaultName}</span>
                    <div class='jump-link' id="${vault.vaultId}" name="${vault.vaultName}" >
                    <a>detail</a>  
                    </div>

               </div>
            </li>
            </c:forEach>

        </ul>



            <ul class="tiles">
                 <c:forEach items="${model.vaults}" var="vault" varStatus="count">
                    <li id="safeLayer">
                       <img src="images/rectangle.png" id="safeBase1" width="30" height="30" />
                       <img src="images/rectangle.png" id="safeBase2"  width="30" height="30"/>
                        <div class="tile tile-small tile-${count.index} slideTextLeft " id="${vault.vaultId}" name="${vault.vaultName}">
                             <div  align="center">
                                <img src="images/vault/personal.png"  />    
                             </div>
                             <div class="nameblock" >
                               <span>${vault.vaultName}</span>
                             </div>
                          </div>    
                        </li>
                    </c:forEach>

            </ul>
            </div>
```

and Here  My Jquery,,,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".tiles").hide();
$(".listUl").show();
```

});

please solve my Problem

Comment: is this asp.................(dot)net??

Comment: The delay maybe could be caused because of the document.ready. In document.ready waits until page it's fully loaded for execute. Maybe could be better if you apply styles for the initial state of the hidden/showing lists.

Comment: can you provide HTML rendered code or any LINK.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `display:none` as default -

`<ul class="tiles" style='display:none;'>`

Answer (score 1):

When first page is loading this time:

-- html is loading first.
-- then javascript executed.

when your page is loading until javascript is executed your list is displaying.

you need use css for this.

in your second  ul :

```
<ul class="tiles" style="display: none;">
```

should done .